# How can I implement LongPress on Recycler View in a CustomAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am implementing long press on RecyclerView. When user long presses on the RecyclerView it shows a menu bar with a delete option. Now I having two problems with this kind of implementation.

First, the menu bar doesn't override the status bar. It pops up above the status bar. The Status bar I am saying is the bar where the application name comes. How do I make it overlap the status bar?

Second, so I changed the way I wrote the code initially and now I am implementing the adapter for recycler view in different java file. I am passing context of the activity from the fragment to this adapter but when I long press it shows this error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.MenuInflater android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getMenuInflater()' on a null object reference 
at onCreateActionMode
```

**This is what I am implementing in my Fragment:**

```
public ModalMultiSelectorCallback mDeleteMode = new ModalMultiSelectorCallback(mMultiSelector) {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            super.onCreateActionMode(actionMode, menu);
            getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_item_delete, menu);
            return true;
        }
```

In the onCreateView in this fragment I do this:

```
context = getActivity();
```

And I send it to my adapter with my ArrayList:

```
customAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(context, myArrayList);
```

In my Custom Adapter I do this:

```
public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<myArrayList> myArrayList) {
        mContext = context;
        this.myArrayList= myArrayList;
    }
```

and in this Adapter, I have an inner class called CustomRecyclerViewHolder where I implement my onLongPress

```
@Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            ((AppCompatActivity) mContext).startSupportActionMode(myFragment.mDeleteMode);
            myFragment.mMultiSelector.setSelected(this, true);
            return true;
        }
```

This ends up in NullPointerException as above. Any ideas why?

Comment: Where are you creating `mDeleteMode`?

Comment: In my fragment class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are using Big Nerd Ranch's [`recyclerview-multiselect`](https://github.com/bignerdranch/recyclerview-multiselect) library, and [this sample code](https://github.com/bignerdranch/recyclerview-multiselect/blob/master/criminalintent-sample/src/main/java/com/bignerdranch/android/criminalintent/CrimeListFragment.java) as the basis for your project. In this sample project, the `ModalMultiSelectorCallback` object is being instantiated within the global scope.

This does not seem like the best place to instantiate this object, considering you are trying to call `getActivity()`, which can be `null` until the fragment's `onCreate()` method is called. I would follow these steps to fix this issue.

First, use [`actionMode.getMenuInflater()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.html#getMenuInflater()) instead of `getActivity()`, as `ActionMode` will provide a `Context`. Next, create a class that extends `ModalMultiSelectorCallback` with your implementation:

```
public class CustomMultiSelectorCallback extends ModalMultiSelectorCallback {

    public CustomMultiSelectorCallback(MultiSelector multiSelector) {
        super(multiSelector);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateActionMode(actionMode, menu);
        actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.crime_list_item_context, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And finally, create the instance of your `ModalMultiSelectorCallback` in the `onCreate()` method of your `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMultiSelector = new MultiSelector();
    mDeleteMode = new CustomMultiSelectorCallback(mMultiSelector);
}
```

Comment: I applied the patch to my code. But I end up getting a null pointer Exception here

`public CustomRecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView, myPrescriptionFragment.mMultiSelector);`

The error is:`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.bignerdranch.android.multiselector.MultiSelector.bindHolder(com.bignerdranch.android.multiselector.SelectableHolder, int, long)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @KamilKamili Well at least it looks like it's making it further down the `Fragment` lifecycle. Now it looks like the `mMultiSelector` is `null` in your `ViewHolder`. This could only happen if the `mMultiSelector` is `null` after `onCreate()`, since the `Adapter` should be set in `onCreateView()`. Are you sure you instantiated `mMultiSelector` in `onCreate()` as well?

Comment: Yes I did, just like how you said

Comment: This is how I did it

`public MultiSelector mMultiSelector;`

    `public MyFragment.CustomMultiSelectorCallback mDeleteMode;`

    `@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mMultiSelector = new MultiSelector();
        mDeleteMode = new MyFragment.CustomMultiSelectorCallback(mMultiSelector);
    }`

Comment: Can you please look at this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982673/how-can-i-override-my-menu-bar-to-come-on-my-application-bar/38982965?noredirect=1#comment65319876_38982965

Comment: Can you please look this problem i am facing since you are the only one I know who knows about the Big Nerd Ranch MultiSelector. ThankYou.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998167/highlighting-rows-of-cardview-in-recyclerview?noredirect=1#comment65350441_38998167

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating your implementation. Instead of doing all your custom handling inside the adapter it should be inside the activity/fragment that is holding it, the adapter should be limited to handling the list itself. The proper way to do this would be to create click listeners in your adapter and have callbacks that you can handle in the same place that you're creating the RecyclerView from.

In your adapter, create an interface:

```
public interface ClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View v, int position);
    void onLongItemClick(View v, int position);
}
```

Then in onCreateViewHolder create the listeners you need:

```
@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_item, parent, false);

    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(v, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
    v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            listener.onLongItemClick(v, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            return true;
        }
    });
    return viewHolder;
}
```

You will need to create the interface when you create your adapter, so handle that in your constructor:

```
public MyAdapter(List<MyObject> list, ClickListener listener) {
    this.list = list;
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

And when you create the adapter:

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(list, new ColorAdapter.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int position) {
            //click logic
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongItemClick(View v, final int position) {
            //long press logic
        }
    });
```

Ideally, once you implement this you'll have no need to pass Context to your adapter, and additional logic and null checks can be handled where they should be, the adapter can be reused for other implementations.