# How can I override my menu bar to come on my application bar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

[image: Weird UI Display]

I have recycler view + viewpager + toolbar in my activity. When I long click on the row in recycler view it should show me a menu bar with a delete option. But this is what I get. Any ideas as to why it is coming above my application name?

**This is the xml of my main activity:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.kaad.sampleproject.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_tool_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_activity_tool_bar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#ff00ff"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:tabTextColor="#d3d3d3" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_activity_tablayout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I kept an add and about menu which never gets displayed for some reason:
**Here is the xml of both my menus:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/menu_bar_main"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_new"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_white_36dp"
        android:title="@string/menu_new"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_about"
        android:title="@string/menu_about"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/menu_bar_delete"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_delete"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:title="@string/delete" />
</menu>
```

**The xml of my styles**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!--<item name="colorPrimary">#FF595951</item>-->
        <!--<item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF5C5C5C</item>-->
        <!--<item name="colorAccent">#FFCCCCCC</item>-->
        <!--<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FF0FF0</item>-->
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

**This is Main Activity:**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_main);

        database = new Database(this);
        categories = database.getCategories();

        myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);


        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_viewpager);
        myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MyMainActivity.this, categories);
        myViewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        myTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_tablayout);
        myTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(myViewPager);

        // Iterate over all tabs and set the custom view
        for (int i = 0; i < myTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            TabLayout.Tab myTab = myTabLayout.getTabAt(i);
            myTab.setCustomView(myPagerAdapter.getTabView(i));
        }
        bus.getInstance().register(this);
    }
```

**This is how I am calling my menu bar in my main prescription fragment**

```
 public class CustomMultiSelectorCallback extends ModalMultiSelectorCallback {

        private int count;
        public CustomMultiSelectorCallback(MultiSelector multiSelector) {
            super(multiSelector);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            super.onCreateActionMode(actionMode, menu);
            count = 0;
            actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_item_delete, menu);
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue for About button:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_about"
    android:title="@string/menu_about"
    app:showAsAction="never"  />
```

update the never part to "ifRoom"

Regarding the menu appearing, can you be more explicit, as to me it seems in Relative Layout you wanted the Toolbar to be top and the views to come after it and that is what it shows.

Comment: I want the menu to override the application bar. And not come on top of it.

Comment: If not mistaken what you are thinking as menu is actually your application bar. The "Sample Category" thing is your Table Layout's name. This is Drawer Layout/ Coordinator Layout kind of thing, where once you click the <- it opens a list of actions. Let me know if I am assuming it all wrong.

Comment: Yes. But isn't the "Simple Category" defined as app name is manifest file?

Comment: Okay let me go back a step, it seems you have this as your content xml. And somewhere you are using this with and <include> option. Please provide the other xml, your main activity.

Comment: I have already provided the xml of my main activity. I am not using any <include> option.

Comment: @Kamil: I am trying to help only by being demanding. Could you provide the main activity please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121098/discussion-between-sumandas-and-kamil-kamili).

Comment: :You are asking for the xml of the main activity. I have already provided it in my question's description. There is no other main activity. Please clarify as to what you want.

Comment: Your java class MainActivity.java or something which invokes this xml.

Comment: @Kamil: Giving a link hoping this tutorial will help: http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

Comment: Thankyou.I will look at it.

Comment: I am not sure, if I understand you correctly, so please explain me one thing: why do you have both a toolbar and a actionbar in your layout? If you want that your toolbar replaces the old actionbar, you should define a "noActionbar" style or <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item> set both to false.

Comment: @DenisLoh I fixed it according to your suggestion and also added `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in OnCreate in my fragments. My add and about menu items show on the toolbar but my delete on longpress is still coming on top of the toolbar and not in it

Comment: If your code here is correct, you have BOTH noActionBar AND windowActionBar=true. Remove the windowActionBar and windowNoTitle lines from your style as they are set by noActionBar style.

Answer (score 0):

So I have solved one of the problems. This is what I edited in my code to display add and about buttons in the toolbar.

First, in your onCreate in the fragments, add this line:

`setHasOptionsMenu(true);`

Second, in your styles, change your theme to something which has `NoActionBar`. In my case I did this:

```
<style name="AppThemeOfStyles"parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#FF595951</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FF5C5C5C</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FFCCCCCC</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FF0FF0</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

I also changed the name of my theme from AppTheme to AppTheme of styles since AppTheme is already a theme defined. So better to change your theme name to something else.

This leads us to the result below:
[image]

But my delete is still coming on the top of the toolbar on longpress.

[image]
Any suggestions, advice will be appreciated :)

**UPDATED:**
Use this in your theme for the overlay to work:
`<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>`

Here is the end result:
[image]